# Conditional statement error in Tkinter Bank Account

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, tkinter

Heres a simple bank account i coded in Python using Tkinter, the issue im having is with the conditional statements in the withdraw and deposit functions, the code always goes with the else statement although in the standard and interest function it should change the value for the TypeOfAccount. Give your insight.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_balance=0):
        self.balance = initial_balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount       
    def get_balance(self, initial_balance, rate):
        return self.get_balance() * self._rate

class BankAccountWithInterest(BankAccount):
  def __init__(self, initial_balance=0, rate=0.1):
     BankAccount.__init__(self, initial_balance)
     self._rate = rate           
  def interest(self):
     return self.balance * self._rate

balance = (randint(100, 500))
my_account = BankAccount(balance)
my_interest = BankAccountWithInterest(balance)
interest = my_interest.balance + my_interest.interest()
print(interest)

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        #Toolbar#

        toolbar = Frame(root)
        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        #Button#

        button1 = Button(toolbar, text="Deposit", width = 13, command=self.depositBalance)
        button2 = Button(toolbar, text="Withdraw",width = 13, command=self.depositWithdraw)
        button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        button2.pack(side=RIGHT)

        #Menu#

        subMenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Type of Account", menu=subMenu)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Standard", command= self.standard)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Interest", command= self.interest)

        #Textbox#

        self.text = Entry(root)
        self.text.pack()

    def standard(self):
        typeOfAcc = "standard"
        w1.config(text=my_account.balance)
        w1.pack()

    def interest(self):
        typeOfAccount = "interest"
        w1.config(text=interest)
        w1.pack()

    def depositBalance(self): 
        if typeOfAccount == "interest":
            a = int(self.text.get())
            interest = interest + a
            w1.config(text=interest)
        elif typeOfAccount == "standard":
            a = int(self.text.get())
            my_account.balance = my_account.balance + a
            print(my_account.balance)
            w1.config(text=my_account.balance)
        else:
            w1.config(text="Error: Select account type")


    def depositWithdraw(self):
        if typeOfAccount == 1:
            a = int(self.text.get())
            interest = interest - a
            w1.config(text=interest)
        elif typeOfAccount == 0:
            a = int(self.text.get())
            my_account.balance = my_account.balance - a
            print(my_account.balance)
            w1.config(text=my_account.balance)
        else:
            w1.config(text="Error: Select account type")

typeOfAccount = 0
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
root.title("Bank Account")
root.minsize(width=250, height=100)
root.maxsize(width=300, height=150)

#Labels#
w = Label(root, text="Current Balance:")
w.pack()
w1 = Label(root, text="0")
w1.pack()

GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please show the complete error.

Comment: typeOfAccount never gets equals interest or standard when the deposit or withdraw button is clicked, it always follows the else statemtn

Comment: I believe my answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155158/how-to-change-value-of-label-after-button-is-clicked-on-tkinter/45155188#45155188) also deals with the problems in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that in your `deposit` function, you are checking if `typeOfAccount` is `'standard'` or `'interest'`, while in your `withdraw` function, you are checking if `typeOfAccount` is `1` or `0`. This inconsistency will cause errors and unexpected behavior.

I also strongly suggest you put these 2 blocks of code:

```
balance = (randint(100, 500))
my_account = BankAccount(balance)
my_interest = BankAccountWithInterest(balance)
interest = my_interest.balance + my_interest.interest()
print(interest)
```

```
typeOfAccount = 0
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
root.title("Bank Account")
root.minsize(width=250, height=100)
root.maxsize(width=300, height=150)

#Labels#
w = Label(root, text="Current Balance:")
w.pack()
w1 = Label(root, text="0")
w1.pack()
```

in your main `GUI` class.

---

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, init_balance=0):
        self.balance = init_balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
    def get_balance(self, init_balance, rate):
        return self.get_balance() * self._rate

class InterestAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, init_balance=0, rate=0.1):
        super().__init__(init_balance)
        self._rate = rate
    def interest(self):
        return self.balance * self._rate

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Bank Account')

        #Menu#
        menu = Menu(self)
        acct_type_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Account Type', menu=acct_type_menu)
        acct_type_menu.add_command(label='Standard', command=self.set_type_standard)
        acct_type_menu.add_command(label='Interest', command=self.set_type_interest)
        self.config(menu=menu)

        #Account#
        start_balance = randint(100, 500)
        self.acct = Account(start_balance)
        self.my_interest = InterestAccount(start_balance)
        self.interest = self.my_interest.balance + self.my_interest.interest()

        #Labels#
        Label(self, text='Current Balance:').pack()
        self.balance_label = Label(self, text='Error: Select account type')
        self.balance_label.pack()

        #Button#
        btns_frame = Frame(self)
        btns_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        Button(btns_frame, text='Deposit', width=13, command=self.deposit).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(btns_frame, text='Withdraw', width=13, command=self.withdraw).pack(side=RIGHT)

        #Textbox#
        self.text = Entry(self)
        self.text.pack()

    def set_type_standard(self):
        self.acct_type = 'standard'
        self.balance_label.config(text=self.acct.balance)

    def set_type_interest(self):
        self.acct_type = 'interest'
        self.balance_label.config(text=self.interest)

    def clear_entry(self):
        self.text.delete(0, END)

    def deposit(self): 
        if self.acct_type == 'interest':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            interest = interest + a
            self.balance_label.config(text=self.interest)
        elif self.acct_type == 'standard':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.acct.balance += a
            self.balance_label.config(text=self.acct.balance)
        else:
            self.balance_label.config(text='Error: Select account type')
        self.clear_entry()

    def withdraw(self):
        if self.acct_type == 'interest':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.interest -= a
            self.balance_label.config(text=self.interest)
        elif self.acct_type == 'standard':
            a = int(self.text.get())
            self.acct.balance -= a
            self.balance_label.config(text=self.acct.balance)
        else:
            self.balance_label.config(text='Error: Select account type')
        self.clear_entry()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().mainloop()
```

### Major Changes:

- made `GUI` inherit from `Tk`
- moved more code into `GUI` class
- altered main `deposit` and `withdraw` methods to use `deposit` and `withdraw` from the `Account` class
- set the initial balance to be `Error: Select account type`

### Minor Changes:

- removed code that did nothing
- clear entry when `Deposit` or `Withdraw` button is clicked
- shortened the 2 account class names
- made method and variable names more appropriate

---

EDIT: Because the `Entry` widget you are using is for deposit and withdrawal amounts, you may want to restrict input of the `Entry` to be numbers and period only:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

        vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%S')
        self.text = Entry(self, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
        self.text.pack()

        ...

    def onValidate(self, S):
        if S in '0123456789.':
            return True
        return False

    ...
```

Comment: thank you, understood all the errors i made, much appreciated